# calculate average value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with datetime as an index. Data are only from Dec, Jan and Feb. I tried to calculate mean value from dec,jan and feb. When I did like:

```
df.resample('a').mean()
```

then it gives me mean value from jan feb dec.

is there anyways to do that in pandas dataframe?

my data looks like:

```
2000-02-29    0.046871
2000-03-31         NaN
2000-04-30         NaN
2000-05-31         NaN
2000-06-30         NaN
2000-07-31         NaN
2000-08-31         NaN
2000-09-30         NaN
2000-10-31         NaN
2000-11-30         NaN
2000-12-31    0.015948
2001-01-31    0.020552
2001-02-28    0.033409
2001-03-31         NaN
2001-04-30         NaN
2001-05-31         NaN
2001-06-30         NaN
2001-07-31         NaN
2001-08-31         NaN
2001-09-30         NaN
2001-10-31         NaN
2001-11-30         NaN
2001-12-31    0.013204
2002-01-31    0.017093
2002-02-28    0.019723
2002-03-31         NaN
2002-04-30         NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%b')).mean()
print (df)
          col
Dec  0.014576
Feb  0.033334
Jan  0.018822
```

If want also years:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%b')).mean()
print (df)
               col
2000-Dec  0.015948
2000-Feb  0.046871
2001-Dec  0.013204
2001-Feb  0.033409
2001-Jan  0.020552
2002-Feb  0.019723
2002-Jan  0.017093
```

Another solution is convert to [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('m')).mean()
print (df)
              col
2000-02  0.046871
2000-12  0.015948
2001-01  0.020552
2001-02  0.033409
2001-12  0.013204
2002-01  0.017093
2002-02  0.019723
```

EDIT:

You need shift one month because `December` and then groupby by `year`:

```
year = df.shift(freq='m').index.year
print (year)
Int64Index([2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001,
            2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001,
            2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002],
           dtype='int64')


df = df.groupby(year).mean()
print (df)
           col
2000  0.046871
2001  0.023303
2002  0.016673
```

Comment: Sorry for not making the question clear. my problem is I tried to caculate average value by taking the values from Dec jan and feb. for example the average value from data of 2000-Dec to 2001-Feb is (0.015948 +0.020552+0.033409)/3 = 0.023303, that is what I am looking for

Comment: OK, now understand. Give me  some time.

Comment: Thank you :) it helps a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! Btw, I first think is possible use season, like `season = (df.index.month % 12 + 3) // 3`, maybe help too ;)